# How to get active perspective name in Eclipse plugin development

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am very new to Eclipse plugin development. I want to get (access) the active perspective name using Java. How do I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();

IWorkbenchWindow win = wb.getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

IWorkbenchPage page = win.getActivePage();

IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective = page.getPerspective();

String label = perspective.getLabel();
```

You can also access the description and the id of the perspective using the methods on IPerspectiveDescriptor.

Comment: Seems ok, but I think it's getActivePage() not getActiveWorkbenchPage().

Comment: You are correct,I checked it on the wiki not on the javadocs, the incorrect method is mentioned here http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_find_the_active_workbench_page%3F  I have updated my answer

Comment: Beware---it seems some of these methods can return `null` if called from the wrong context.

Comment: Is there en e4 way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at ["Using Perspectives in the Eclipse UI](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/using-perspectives/PerspectiveArticle.html)".

If you have access to an object of type [IWorkbenchWindow](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IWorkbenchWindow.html):

```
window.getActivePage().getPerspective().getLabel()
```

Comment: Is there en e4 way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The new E4 way relies on the [**`EModelService`**](https://help.eclipse.org/2018-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Findex.html&cp=2_1_1).

Simply as:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.advanced.MPerspective;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.basic.MWindow;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.modeling.EModelService;

@Inject EModelService modelService;    
@Inject MWindow window;

MPerspective p =  modelService.getActivePerspective(window);
System.out.println("ACTIVE PERSPECTIVE: " + p.getLabel());
```